# What to use std::optional or std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, option-type, unique-ptr

I have a class with a member that is dynamic allocated (it's allocated only when it will be used).

Think something like that:

```
class A {};

class B {
    A* aMember;
};
```

what would be better to replace `A*`: `std::optional` or `std::unique_ptr` ?

and when to use `std::optional` instead `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Does B _own_ the pointed-to A?  Is an optional holding `nullptr` meaningful in your program?

Comment: sure `std::optional` will skip dynamic allocation. This usually lead to better performance and less memory overhead. If `aMember` was dynamically allocated only to be able to be null, my choice would be `std::optional`

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom yes, B is responsible to create and destroy it.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot "dynamically allocated only to be able to be null" its true.

Comment: @VictorAurélio Then I'd recommend using `std::optional` then. But be aware that just like values, polymiphism will not work, eg you cannot hold a subclass of `A` in the optional.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`std::optional<A>` guarantees that no auxiliary memory allocation will take place. This means that the raw buffer for the potential object of type `A` is embedded into `std::optional<A>`. It is an integral part of `std::optional`'s memory footprint. This means that the memory size of `std::optional<A>` will *always* be at least `sizeof(A)`, regardless of whether that optional `A` object currently lives or not. That is how much `std::optional<A>` will contribute to the total size of `B`.

`std::unique_ptr<A>` is a pointer. Its size is about the same as the size of a regular naked pointer. That is how much memory `std::unique_ptr<A>` itself occupies inside `B`. In order to make it point to a valid `A` object you will have to allocate that `A` elsewhere, independently. When `A` exists, it occupies memory. When `A` does not exist it does not occupy memory.

The above is something to take into account when making your decision. `std::optional<A>` does not involve dynamic memory allocation/deallocation, but the price you pay for that is potentially "wasted" memory inside your `std::optional<A>`. Using `std::optional` for massively instantiated and/or large objects might prove to be quite wasteful, especially if the object spends most of its lifetime in empty state.

This means that the purpose of `std::optional` is not exactly aimed at optional long-term storage. `std::optional` is something to be used *locally*: e.g. as optional local values, optional parameters of functions, optional return values. Long-term use is also OK, as long as you are not instantiating such objects in massive numbers.

`std::unique_ptr<A>` does not waste memory, but the price you pay for that is dynamic memory allocation/deallocation.

Of course, ownership semantics is also quite different. `std::optional` is copyable. `std::unique_ptr` is movable, but not copyable.

Comment: So a rule of thumb for someone considering this question for lazily instantiated members (i.e. any that can't be constructed when the containing class is) would be to assess what proportion of runtime that object is likely to be alive, and what size it is, and if it's a large object that might only sometimes or briefly be alive, just keep using `unique_ptr`.